# Complicated Time Between Calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need some help with creating a complicated date/time calculation. I've got 2 columns with timestamps (date plus time). I need to find the difference but this is what I need the formula to do:

- Calculate the day/hour/minute between 2 timestamps
- Leave the cell blank if the Assigned column is blank
- Consider business days and business hours (not sure if both is possible)
- Return the calculation in a simple format - Days, Hours, Minutes. - In a perfect scenario, it would only display each type (days/hours/minutes) if its returning a value other than 0. E.G. one cell might say 03 minutes, another might say 2 hours, 18 minutes. Not 0 days, 0 hours, 03 minutes, etc.

Hope this makes sense and is possible. Googling comes up with a whole host of answers but none are specific enough. Thanks!

Comment: Your best off with a VBA function, if you want to include all of those specifications.  And, in that case, would a "day" be 24 hours, or would it be "business hours"?

Comment: Business hours. M-F 9-5, excluding weekends and holidays.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest two methods,

1. Calculate *Days, Hours & Minutes including 
   Holidays*.
2. Calculate *Days, Hours & Minutes excluding 
   Holidays*.

[image]

**Formula for Method 1 in Cell `D241:`**

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B241),ISBLANK(A241)),"No Data",INT(B241-A241)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(B241-A241,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(B241-A241,1))&" Minutes")
```

**Formula for Method 2 in Cell `D248:`**

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B248),ISBLANK(A248)),"No Data",NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A248,B248,1,$F$248:$F$250)&" days "&INT((B248-A248-INT(B248-A248))*24)&" hours "&INT((B248-A248-(INT((B248-A248-INT(B248-A248))*24)/24)-INT(B248-A248))*24*60)&" mins")
```

*Fill down both formula.*

**N.B.**

1. For benefit of community I've included 
   **Method 1**, you and readers may ignore it.
2. Adjust **list of Holidays** and *cell 
   references* in the Formula as needed.
3. You may also replace **No Data** error message 
   with **Blank Space**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a User Defined Function (UDF) in view of all your requirements.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=elapsedWrkTime(A2,B2,Holidays)` in some cell.

If you study the code, you should be able to figure out the algorithm used.

- Working hours are computed based on hours 9-5
- Times worked outside of this, or on weekends or holidays, are not counted.
- Once we have that information, the days/hours/minutes output is created and formatted.

You will need to test it and confirm it provides the output you are looking for, and calculates accurately.

```
Option Explicit
Function elapsedWrkTime(startDT As Date, endDt As Date, Holidays As Range) As Variant
    Const WORKING_DAY_START As Date = #9:00:00 AM#
    Const WORKING_DAY_END As Date = #5:00:00 PM#
    Dim adjTimeStart As Date, adjTimeEnd As Date, totTime As Date
    Dim D As Date

For D = DateValue(startDT) To DateValue(endDt)
    If Not isHoliday(D, Holidays) Then
    Select Case Weekday(D)
        Case 2 To 6 'Workday Mon-Fri
            'Adj for first and last days
            If D = DateValue(startDT) Then
                If TimeValue(startDT) <= WORKING_DAY_START Then
                    adjTimeStart = 0
                ElseIf TimeValue(startDT) >= WORKING_DAY_END Then
                    adjTimeStart = WORKING_DAY_START - WORKING_DAY_END
                Else
                    adjTimeStart = WORKING_DAY_START - TimeValue(startDT)
                End If
            End If

            If D = DateValue(endDt) Then
                If TimeValue(endDt) >= WORKING_DAY_END Then
                    adjTimeEnd = 0
                ElseIf TimeValue(endDt) <= WORKING_DAY_START Then
                    adjTimeEnd = WORKING_DAY_START - WORKING_DAY_END
                Else
                    adjTimeEnd = TimeValue(endDt) - WORKING_DAY_END
                End If
            End If

            totTime = totTime + WORKING_DAY_END - WORKING_DAY_START
    End Select
    End If
Next D

'elapsedWrkTime = totTime + adjTimeStart + adjTimeEnd


'Format the output as a text string


Dim dys As Long, hrs As Long, mns As Long
Dim wrkHrs As Double
Dim totWorkTime As Double

wrkHrs = (WORKING_DAY_END - WORKING_DAY_START) * 24
totWorkTime = (totTime + adjTimeStart + adjTimeEnd) * 24
dys = Int(totWorkTime / wrkHrs)

totWorkTime = totWorkTime - dys * wrkHrs
hrs = Int(totWorkTime)
mns = (totWorkTime - Int(totWorkTime)) * 60

Dim strOut As String
Select Case dys
    Case 1
        strOut = "1 day "
    Case Is > 1
        strOut = Format(dys, "0"" days """)
End Select
Select Case hrs
    Case 1
        strOut = strOut & "1 hour "
    Case Is > 1
        strOut = strOut & Format(hrs, "0"" hours """)
End Select
Select Case mns
    Case 1
        strOut = strOut & "1 minute"
    Case Is > 1
        strOut = strOut & Format(mns, "0"" minutes""")
End Select

If strOut = "" Then
    elapsedWrkTime = "No work hrs computed"
Else
    elapsedWrkTime = strOut
End If

End Function

Private Function isHoliday(dt As Date, Holidays As Range) As Boolean
    Dim v, w
v = Holidays
For Each w In v
    If Int(dt) = w Then
        isHoliday = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next w
isHoliday = False
End Function
```

[image]